# Cant Link an Async Task to positive button of Dialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-dialog

I am trying to create a Dialog box in android with 2 buttons and link the respective positive and negative button to a async task both going to the same activity. But the dialog is not getting created. Can anyone please help?

```
public class VotingActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_voting);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        final String id = bundle.getString("DiscussionId");
        final String distext = bundle.getString("Discussiontext");
        final String detaildesc = bundle.getString("Detaildesc");
        final String gpid = bundle.getString("groupid");
        TextView discussiontext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.discussiondesc);
        TextView detailsdesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detaildesc);

        discussiontext.setText(distext);
        detailsdesc.setText(detaildesc);



        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(VotingActivity.this);
        adb.setMessage("Choose Your Choise");
        adb.setTitle("Hello");
        adb.setPositiveButton("Support", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> ar =   new UpdateVotingCountDataSource(id,R.id.support,gpid).execute();
                try {
                    if(ar.get()==true){

                        System.out.println("Update successfully");

                        Intent in = new Intent(VotingActivity.this,ChatActivity.class);
                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        b.putString("disid", id);
                        b.putString("distext", distext);
                        b.putString("detaildesc",detaildesc );
                        in.putExtras(b);
                        startActivity(in);
                    }


                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });


        adb.setNegativeButton("Against", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {



            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> ar =   new UpdateVotingCountDataSource(id,R.id.against,gpid).execute();


                try {
                    if(ar.get()==true){

                        System.out.println("Update succssfully");
                        Intent in = new Intent(VotingActivity.this,ChatActivity.class);
                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        b.putString("disid", id);
                        b.putString("distext", distext);
                        b.putString("detaildesc",detaildesc );
                        in.putExtras(b);
                        startActivity(in);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }




            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });


adb.show();
        }








    }
```

Comment: You haven't called `adb.show();`

Comment: But I still cant link it to the ChatActivity.java

Comment: @user3552386 really what do you wish to do? 

1) The Alert Dialog buttons, for support and against, you have the same code running, then why use the alert dialog there?

2) Also on click the against button of your view, you still wish to move onto ChatActivity, with the same async task.

Can you detail what you wish to achieve?

Comment: The purpose of this activity is just to count numbers of supports and against. ar is the async task. Still I am unable to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add adb.show() without which the dialog wont be shown.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But still it is not going the chatActivity.java.

Comment: Can you atleast see the popup?

Comment: Also asynctask will not return anything till it executes. Start the activity to onPostExecute() of the asynctask, and it will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the ar.get() will be false until the ar finish. Try moving the activity-switching code in the postExecute() of your AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the alertbuilder like below intiialize

```
Alertdialog alert;(above on create)
  alert = adb.create();
            adb.show();
```